# How to convert array to dictionary with SwiftyJSON?

Tags: arrays, swift, swifty-json

I restructured my endpoint return and want my front end code to work with the old way. I have 3 values in an array and would like to convert it to a dictionary `[Int64: JSON]`. I'm using SwiftyJSON. Thank you.

What I have:

```
let time = JSON(rawValue: x)!.int64Value                   //1614748500
let like = point["val"].int64Value                         //91
let dislike = JSON.init(integerLiteral: trend.rawValue)    //3

// po print(array) [1614748500, 91, 3]
                    0 element

// po arrray ▿ 3 elements
             - 0 : 1614748500
             - 1 : 91
             - 2 : 3
```

What I want it to be

```
 //  po print(array) [1614748500: [
                 1614748500,
                 91,
                 3
                 ]
                 0 element

 //  po array ▿ 1 elements
              ▿ 0 : 2 elements
              - key : 1614748500
              ▿ value : [
                1614748500,
                91,
                3
               ]
             ▿ rawArray : 3 elements
             - 0 : 1614748500
             - 1 : 91
             - 2 : 3
             - rawDictionary : 0 elements
             - rawString : ""
             - rawNumber : 0
             - rawNull : <null>
             - rawBool : false
             - type : SwiftyJSON.Type.array
             - error : nil
```

Comment: So what's the error/issue? Where are you stuck?

Comment: No, there is no error. I just don't know how to convert it from a an array to like the bottom part of array. :(

Comment: Well you should Google that, and you should be able to fix it. For a hint, I am not sure. It seems every first element of your array has to be a key of dictionary. So get first index element, make it a key and assign that array back.

Comment: I did look it up but couldn't find a solution for 2 days so I'm hoping SOF will be able to help.

Comment: How _do you want to_ convert your array to a dictionary? The logic for this is far from clear?

Comment: Do you have a reason for using SwifttyJSON instead of using the Apple provided Encodable and Decodable protocols?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Took me a while finally figured it out.

```
var dict = [Int64: JSON]()

let time = JSON(rawValue: x)!.int64Value                   //1614748500
let like = point["val"].int64Value                         //91
let dislike = JSON.init(integerLiteral: trend.rawValue)    //3

dict[time] = JSON(arrayLiteral: time, like, dislike)

 po print(dict)
    [1614748500: [
    1614748500,
    91,
    3
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have an array of 3 elements and want to convert it to a dictionary with three key value pairs. To do this, you first decide what keys you will use. Could be “first”, “second”, and “third”, but hopefully you have more meaningful keys. And then you convert like this:

```
let array = [“string1”, “string2”, “string3”]
let dict = [“first”: array[0], “second”: array[1], “third”: array[2]]
```

That’s all. And there’s really no need for a third party library for JSON.

And [Int64: JSON] is certainly not a dictionary. Dictionary = key/value pairs. For JSON dictionaries the keys must be strings.